# Prove that $\lim_{x\to\frac {\pi}{2}+}\tan x=-\infty.$

Tags: real-analysis

Prove that $\lim_{x\to\frac {\pi}{2}-}\tan x=\infty$ and $\lim_{x\to\frac{\pi}{2}+}\tan x=-\infty.$

The domain of $\tan x$ is $A=\Bbb R\setminus\{2n\pi \pm \frac{\pi}{2}: n\in\Bbb Z\}.$

In order to prove $\lim_{x\to\frac {\pi}{2}-}\tan x=\infty$ I need to show that for any $M\in\Bbb R$ we have a, $\delta\gt 0$ such that, if $0\lt \frac{\pi}2-x \lt \delta$ and $x\in A$  we have, $\tan x\gt M.$

And in order to prove $\lim_{x\to\frac {\pi}{2}+}\tan x=-\infty$ I need to show that for any $M\in\Bbb R$ we have a, $\delta\gt 0$ such that, if $0\lt x-\frac{\pi}2 \lt \delta$ and $x\in A$  we have, $\tan x\lt M.$

I was able to prove that, $\lim_{x\to\frac {\pi}{2}-}\tan x=\infty$ as follows:

> Let $M\in\Bbb R.$ We fix, $\delta=\frac{\pi}2-\arctan M\gt 0.$ If $x\in A$ and $\frac{\pi}2-\delta =\arctan M\lt x\lt \frac{\pi}{2}$ then, as $\tan x$ is strictly increasing on $(-\frac{\pi}{2},\frac{\pi}2)$ and $-\frac{\pi}{2}\lt \arctan M\lt x\lt \frac{\pi}{2}$ we have, $\tan(\arctan M)=M\lt \tan x.$
>
> Thus, for $M\in \Bbb R,\exists \delta(=\frac{\pi}2-\arctan M\gt 0)$ such that, if $x\in A$ and $(\frac{\pi}2-\delta =\arctan M\lt x\lt \frac{\pi}{2}\iff -\delta\lt x-\frac{\pi}{2}\lt 0  \iff )0\lt \frac{\pi}{2}-x\lt \delta,$ we have, $\tan x\gt M.$
>
> As, $M\in\Bbb R$ is arbitrary, so, we have, $\lim_{x\to\frac {\pi}{2}-}\tan x=\infty.$

I am now trying prove $\lim_{x\to\frac{\pi}{2}+}\tan x=-\infty,$ in a similar way, but somewhere I am getting stuck. Is there a way to prove this using a similar argument as we did for the case, $\lim_{x\to\frac {\pi}{2}-}\tan x=\infty$ ? Any help regarding this issue will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: $\lim_{x\to\frac {\pi}{2}+} \tan x$ usually denotes the limit from the right, so that should be $-\infty$, and $\lim_{x\to\frac{\pi}{2}-}\tan x=+\infty$.

Comment: Have you tried working with $\tan(x) = \sin(x)/\cos(x)$ ? The numerator is close to $1$ if $x$ is close to $\pi/2$, and the denominator is close to zero (positive if $x < \pi/2$ and negative if $x > \pi/2$).

Comment: @MartinR The approach you mention is a really good way to understand that indeed $\lim_{x\to\frac {\pi}{2}+}\tan x=-\infty$ and $\lim_{x\to\frac{\pi}{2}-}\tan x=\infty$ holds true intuitively, but writing the proof rigorously is creating the problem for me.

Comment: Do you know that $\tan(\pi/2+h)=-\cot h$?  Now use $h\to 0^+$.

Answer (score 2):

The *idea* (for the left limit) is that if $x$ is close to, but less than, $\pi/2$ then $\sin(x)$ is close to one, and $\cos(x)$ is positive and close to zero, so that the quotient becomes arbitrarily large.

*Concretely:* Consider the case $\frac \pi 4 < x < \frac \pi 2$. Then
$$
 \sin(x) > \sin (\frac \pi 4) = \frac{1}{\sqrt 2}
$$
and
$$
 0 < \cos(x) = \sin(\frac \pi 2 - x) \le \frac \pi 2 - x
$$
and therefore
$$
 \tan(x) \ge \frac{1/\sqrt 2}{\frac \pi 2 - x} \, .
$$
It follows that $\tan(x) > M> 0$ if $0 < \frac \pi 2 - x < \delta :=  \min(\frac{1}{\sqrt 2 M}, \frac \pi 4)$.

This proves that the left limit at $\pi/2$ is $+\infty$, the right limit works similarly.

Comment: Can you please confirm one thing: The domain of $\tan x$ is $A=\Bbb R\setminus\{2n\pi \pm \frac{\pi}{2}: n\in\Bbb Z\},$ right?

Comment: @ThomasFinley: That is correct, you can also express it as $\Bbb R\setminus\{(2n+1) \frac{\pi}{2}: n\in\Bbb Z\}$

Comment: Thanks! I was able to prove that $\lim_{x\to\frac {\pi}{2}-}\tan x=\infty$ and I attached my proof in the original post but is there a way to prove that $\lim_{x\to\frac{\pi}{2}+}\tan x=-\infty$ using a similar argument? I have edited my original post, and it'll be really very helpful if you consider taking a look at it.

Comment: @ThomasFinley: I tried to answer your *original* question with a rigorous but elementary proof that does not use the properties of the $\arctan$ functions. Now you have changed your question significantly, so I will no longer participate in this discussion.

Comment: Ok, thanks for your help though!

Answer (score -1):

Suppose we want to show that $\displaystyle \lim_{x \rightarrow \frac{\pi}{2}^-} \tan x = \infty$. Consider the interval $[0,\frac{\pi}{2})$, such that $\tan x$ is strictly increasing and has an inverse. As you said, you want to show that for any $M$, there exists $\delta > 0$ such that $0 < \frac{\pi}{2}-x < \delta \implies \tan x > M$.

Start by fixing a choice of $M.$ Let $M'$ be the unique value in $[0,\frac{\pi}{2})$ such that $\tan M' = M$. Thus pick $\delta = \frac{\pi}{2}-M' > 0$, such that $0 < \frac{\pi}{2}-x < \delta \implies \frac{\pi}{2}-\delta < x < \frac{\pi}{2} \implies M' < x < \frac{\pi}{2}$. But from monotonicity, we have that $\tan x > M$ for all $x$ in this range.

Comment: If one can use the fact that  the tangent  function maps $[0, \pi/2)$ onto $[0, \infty)$ then this is a good approach.

Comment: Hmm, unfortunately I'm not sure what OP's query really is anymore - he seems to have included my idea and passed it off as his own...

Comment: @Bananas I am sorry, although your approach similar to mine, but I found this way of proving in a book and this  only makes me wanna conclude that this is a pretty standard approach. But the thing is, how to prove, $\lim_{x\to\frac {\pi}{2}+}\tan x=-\infty$ using a similar reasoning. This is explicitly my issue as it stands now.

Comment: @Bananas But indeed, although I did not notice your answer first, thanks for putting it here. If you want, I can add a line stating "My solution is similar to this approach..." or something like that.

Comment: @ThomasFinley, as Martin R pointed out, if you are allowed to use the fact that the tangent function maps $(-\frac{\pi}{2},\pi]$ onto $(-\infty,0]$ then one can adopt a similar proof to what I wrote above. In particular, for any choice of $M$, let $M'$ be in this interval such that $\tan M' = M$. Then choose $\delta = M' - \frac{\pi}{2}$. You should be able to take it from here.